# How to add PyTorch LTS version in setup.py?

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, dependencies, setup.py

I would like to know how I can include pytorch **LTS** version in my setup.py file for a library.

From the instructions on https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#start-locally , we can see that it needs additional information to find the package.
Here is the command they suggest :
`pip3 install torch==1.8.2+cu111 torchvision==0.9.2+cu111 torchaudio==0.8.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/lts/1.8/torch_lts.html`

Note the flag at the end `-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/lts/1.8/torch_lts.html`

I would like to know, how to include such option in a setup.py.

## What I have tried

- Using dependency_links, but it is now deprecated and ignored.
- Using command line flag `-f` when trying to install my library (`pip install -e . -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/lts/1.8/torch_lts.html` ). This works but this is not a solution as it would require to enter it every time and would become hard to maintain with more url.

## Setup.py

Here is what my setup.py looks like for now.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="my_library",
    version="0.1",
    description="my library description",
    packages=["my_library"],
    python_requires=">=3.8",
    install_requires=[
        "torch==1.8.2+cu111@https://download.pytorch.org/whl/lts/1.8/torch_lts.html",
        "torchvision==0.9.2+cu111@https://download.pytorch.org/whl/lts/1.8/torch_lts.html",
        "pillow>=8.0.0",
        "numpy>=1.21.0",
        "timm==0.4.12",
    ]
)
```

## Steps to reproduce issue

1. `pip install -e . --no-cache-dir`

## Actual Output

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.8.2+cu111@https://download.pytorch.org/whl/lts/1.8/torch_lts.html (from mdai-core==0.1) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.8.2+cu111@https://download.pytorch.org/whl/lts/1.8/torch_lts.html
```

## Expected Output

No error and install process of pytorch lts should begin.

PS : The `==` in the version requirements is for testing purposes so that it doesn't download the 1.9 non-LTS. Once we'll be sure it uses the LTS we'll be a ble to use `>=` as it seems to be the recommended approach for libraries.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Pytorch just deprecated Pytorch LTS.
While this question is unanswered, since Pytorch LTS will be removed, it is not a relevant question anymore and one should move to a supported version of Pytorch instead.

Source: https://pytorch.org/blog/pytorch-enterprise-support-update/